# php daily email report

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have created a CRON job to run every morning at 8.30 in order to send a report to a specific email address.
However, the report works off the user entering specific dates. I was wondering how I can change the $_post value from the start and end date variables to 'todays' and yesterdays date.

here is the code:

```
session_start();  
$s = $_POST['$yesterday'];  
$e = $_POST['$today'];  
$i = $_SESSION['user'];  
$m = "VACANCY APPLICATIONS REPORT FROM $s TO $e \r\n\r\n";  
$conn = mysqli_connect("");

$em = "email address";  
$vrquery = "SELECT jobid,role,jobtype,vacancyref FROM job ORDER BY jobid";    

$vrresult = mysqli_query($conn, $vrquery);  
while($vrrow=mysqli_fetch_array($vrresult))  
{
$m = $m . $vrrow['vacancyref'] . " " . $vrrow['role'] . " " . $vrrow['jobtype'] .    "\r\n\r\n";  
$vquery = "SELECT cname,ctel,cemail FROM candidatejob,cv,candidate WHERE           jobid=".$vrrow['jobid']." AND candidatejob.cvid=cv.cvid AND cv.cid=candidate.cid AND   cvdate>='$s' AND cvdate<='$e' ORDER BY cname";  
$vresult = mysqli_query($conn, $vquery);  
while($vrow=mysqli_fetch_array($vresult))  
{  
    $m = $m . $vrow['cname'] . " " . $vrow['ctel'] . " " . $vrow['cemail'] .   "\r\n";  
}  
$m = $m . "\r\n\r\n";  
}
$m = $m . "\r\n\r\nALL CANDIDATES SUBMITTING CVs WITHIN DATES\r\n\r\n";
$cvquery = "SELECT cname,ctel,cemail FROM cv,candidate WHERE cv.cid=candidate.cid AND     cvdate>='$s' AND cvdate<='$e' ORDER BY cname";
$cvresult = mysqli_query($conn, $cvquery);
while($cvrow=mysqli_fetch_array($cvresult))
{
    $m = $m . $cvrow['cname'] . " " . $cvrow['ctel'] . " " . $cvrow['cemail'] . "\r\n";
}

$conn->close();  


$headers = "From: no-reply@nortech.org.uk\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();  
mail($em, " Daily Job Applications Report", $m, $headers);  

?>
```

the cron job works great, however it is not returning any results from the database. I know the connection is correct because it is the same on ALL my pages and they all work. can anyone please help and offer advice as to why it's not pulling from the database?

Much appreciated

Comment: did you enable debug mode and display all errors and warnings?

Comment: what about these variables $yesterday and $today

Comment: what does mysqli_connect_errno() say?

Comment: the $yesterday and $today variables are declared at the top of the page above session_start();   so the variables read:   $today = date("F d, Y");    
$yesterday = date("F d, Y", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);

Comment: the debugger keeps giving this error message "
 Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()" I have altered the php.ini file and ensured the libmysql_e.dll file is within the System 32 folder. I'm at a loss....

Comment: is this extension really enabled? what does phpinfo() say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get today's date, following the coding style above:

$e = date("Y-m-d");

To get yesterday's date:

$s = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Also why do you have dollar signs in the $_POST variable names?